# State or workflow diagram component for .NET

Tags: .net, workflow, components, statechart

I'm looking for a component or library for .NET, that would allow me to either visually edit, or at least visualise simple state or workflow diagrams or charts.

Preferably free, but comercial is fine too.

Anyone have any recomendation or experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the commercial ones that I'm aware of:

- [AddFlow](http://www.lassalle.com/)
- [FlowChart.NET](http://www.mindfusion.eu/flowchart-net.html)
- [ILog.NET](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/visualization/diagram-net/)
- [Nevron Diagram](http://www.nevron.com/Products.DiagramFor.NET.Overview.aspx)

and also I know one that is free but a bit outdated: http://code.google.com/p/diagramnet/